# Direct command and using bat file difference?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I can get image size with this code if I run direct cmd:

```
identify -format "%wx%h" E:\Image.jpg
```

(the result = 640x480)

However, if I put this code in a bat file,

```
@echo off
identify -format "%wx%h" E:\Image.jpg
```

it doesn't work.
so, (the result = h)  ??

How can I do this. Thanks...

Comment: A script interprets `%wx%` as a (probably not defined) variable and replaces it with its value (probably nothing). The command line parser is slightly different: it keeps the literal `%xw%` when the variable is not defined. In a batch script. double the `%`  to `%%` to escape them (treat them as a literal `%`): `identify -format "%%wx%%h" E:\Image.jpg`

Comment: [in case, you are interested in the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts?r=Saves_AllUserSaves), but be warned - it's hard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Switch % to %% in a Batchfile.](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/075/Q75634/)
Your code should be something like: `identify -format "%wx%h" E:\Image.jpg`

Comment: Are you sure, you didn't forget to double them? `;)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. By the way how can I set a value this result.